# Squid, autossh and acl denial

Tags: ssh, squid, ssh-tunnel

I've got a squid.conf that looks like this:

```
cache_mgr me@example.com
visible_hostname example.com
httpd_suppress_version_string on
via off
```

http_port 3128 transparent

acl all src all
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny all

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid

coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

And an autossh tunnel that looks like this:

> sudo autossh -C -N -L 3128:example.com:3128 -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa -M 20000 me@example.com

I must have some misconfiguration: every http connection over the tunnel is 403'ed at squid. I don't see what I've done wrong. Can someone pull me out of the woods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `-L 3128:localhost:3128` instead so you connect to squid on the loopback interface.

Comment: That was entirely the problem. Thank you kindly, Eduardo.